# ryby nokogiri XML parse

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

При опросе устройства получаю ответ в XML следующего вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RESPONSE>
  <OBJECT basetype="status" name="status" oid="1">
    <PROPERTY name="response-type">success</PROPERTY>
    <PROPERTY name="response-type-numeric">0</PROPERTY>
    <PROPERTY name="response">957795f3ef7f8b0b8c36af59e4ee9295</PROPERTY>
    <PROPERTY name="return-code">1</PROPERTY>
  </OBJECT>
</RESPONSE>
```

Если быть точным:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><RESPONSE><OBJECT basetype=\"status\" name=\"status\" oid=\"1\"><PROPERTY name=\"response-type\">success</PROPERTY><PROPERTY name=\"response-type-numeric\">0</PROPERTY><PROPERTY name=\"response\">957795f3ef7f8b0b8c36af59e4ee9295</PROPERTY><PROPERTY name=\"return-code\">1</PROPERTY></OBJECT></RESPONSE>\n"
```

При разборе nokagiri при попытке поиска значения response получаю nil.

```
msa_response = Nokogiri::XML(response)
msa_session_id = msa_response.at_xpath('//response')
```

Как корректно получить значение rsponse?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался:

```
msa_response = Nokogiri::XML(@msaresponse.body)

#p msa_session_id
#msa_response.xpath('//PROPERTY').each do |link|
#       p link.content
#end
p msa_response.xpath('//PROPERTY')[2].content
```